What might be Macron's reason to call for a new election right after he lost one?
The 2024 European Parliament elections were clearly a loss for Macron's party. In a surprise action, he dissolved Parliament and initiated a new election.
As the president of France, he can do it as a single-person decision, although both he and the parliament are elected directly by the people.
I think, in such a situation, he should have allowed the parliament to fulfill its term, because they could have used that time to repair their popularity. Now they have much less time for that. The likely result will be that they also lose this election.
Why would Macron call a snap election immediately after losing one?
